# Paint bottom side of a circle and place Image on the remaining side android custom Imageview

Tags: java, android, kotlin, view, android-custom-view

After drawing a circle on imageview (Extending imageview) custom view, I want to paint the bottom side (30%) and place an image on the other top side (70%). The illustration can be viewed [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n7LiJsyXD_4gr5LQlo4fkQWm29SgE8OP/view?usp=sharing)

The circle was drawn with the below link

```
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)

        radiusPaint.color = getClassificationColor(classificationText)
        radiusPaint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        radiusPaint.strokeWidth = borderWidth
        canvas?.drawCircle(mWidth / 2f, mHeight / 2f, mRadius, radiusPaint)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should do the trick:

```
lateinit var imagePaint: Paint
lateinit var shadePaint: Paint
lateinit var shadeRect: RectF
lateinit var bitmap: Bitmap
lateinit var clearOutSide: Path

private fun init() {
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.resources, R.drawable.example_image)
    mWidth = bitmap.width.toFloat()
    mHeight = bitmap.height.toFloat();
    mRadius = mWidth / 2
    
    imagePaint = Paint()
    shadePaint = Paint()
    
    // going with the assumption that mWidth = mHeight = 2 * mRadius
    shadeRect = RectF(0f,mHeight * 0.7f, mWidth, mHeight ) // this will be the shade area, could probably done various other ways
    shadePaint.color = Color.GRAY
    // shadePaint.maskFilter = BlurMaskFilter(20f, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL) // a BlurMaskFilterMightLook decent

    clearOutSide = Path()
    clearOutSide.addRect(RectF(0f, 0f, mWidth, mHeight), Path.Direction.CW)
    clearOutSide.addCircle(mWidth / 2, mHeight / 2, mRadius, Path.Direction.CCW)
}

override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
    super.onDraw(canvas)
    canvas?.drawRect(0f, 0f, mWidth, mHeight, shadePaint)
    canvas?.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0f, 0f, imagePaint)
    canvas?.drawRect(shadeRect, shadePaint)
    canvas?.clipPath(clearOutSide)
    canvas?.drawColor(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR) // clear the image outside the circle
}
```